# jQuery - select parent by child class?

Tags: jquery, dom

How can I select the `<tr>` containing the child `<div class="test">`, as below?

```
<table>
  <tr> <!-- this tr is what I want to select -->
    <td>
      <div class="test"> text </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 41):

You can use [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for that, depending on your needs:

```
$("div.test").parents("tr");
// Or
$("div.test").closest("tr");
```

(The initial selector can be anything that matches your `div`, so `".test"` would be fine too.)

`parents` will look all the way up the tree, possibly matching multiple `tr` elements if you have a table within a table. `closest` will stop with the first `tr` it encounters for each of the `div`s.

Here's an example using `closest`:

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/usiqir) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/usiqir/edit)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="first"> <!-- this tr I want to select -->
    <td>
      <div class="test"> text </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="second"> <!-- this tr I want to select -->
    <td>
      <div class="test"> text </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="third"> <!-- this tr I want to select -->
    <td>
      <div class="test"> text </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var rows = $("div.test").closest("tr");
  display("Matched " + rows.length + " rows:");
  rows.each(function() {
    display("Row '" + this.id + "'");
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Output:

```
Matched 3 rows:
Row 'first'
Row 'second'
Row 'third'
```

Answer (score 9):

Use selector :has() like:

```
$("tr:has(div.test)");
```

Find jQuery documentation here [:has() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.test').parent('tr')
```

this selects exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

you should use

```
$('.test').parents('tr');
```

For Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7T9nN/

Answer (score 3):

The below targets the parent  with class of .test somewhere within its children and in the below example changes background  to red...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.test').parents('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

For me this is extremely powerful when trying to target  exported html from indesign. Powerful because indesign does not let you tag 's but through this you can tag a  and then the  through this JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.test').parent().parent();` or `$('.text').parent().closest('tr');`