# jQuery - How do you select a parent based on the attribute of a child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you select a parent based on the attribute of a child?

I want to select a div:

that has a child with the radio:checked

```
<div> <input id="1" type="radio"/> </div>
<div> <input id="2" type="radio"/> </div>
```

for example.

```
$('div radio:checked').click(function(){
     $(*** div parent based on radio:checked ***).css({'background':'#F00'});
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - select parent by child class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557005/jquery-select-parent-by-child-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('div radio:checked').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').css({'background':'#F00'});
});
```

if you want the nearest 'parent' div, even if it is several levels up.

[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('div radio:checked').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').css({'background':'#F00'});
});
```

if you want the direct parent

Interestingly, you can do a sort of reverse lookup selector with [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has/) like

```
$('div:has(radio:checked)').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'#F00'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('div radio:checked').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().css({'background':'#F00'});
});
```

**UPDATE:**

the **'div radio:checked'** do not work in your code, you can use:

```
$('div input[type=radio]').click(function () {
 $(this).parent().css({'background': '#F00'});
});
```